# Change the querystring pattern of web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

If we put a variable (say it is `myvariable`) in the action method such as

```
[RoutePrefix("api/myservice")]      
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetVar([FromUri] string myvariable = "")
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "");
        return response;
    }
```

}
, the api's url will look like:
`api/myservice?myvariable={ myvariable }`

But I want to see it like:
`api/myservice?myvariable={ var }` `var` or anything else rather than `myvariable`.

how can I do it without changing route table?

Comment: Could you explain more about {myvariable} and {var}?

Comment: I have updated the issue. Please look into it again. myvariable is the name of variable and {myvariable} means the R-value of the query string key-value parameter and so does { var }